# Changing iphone lock screen programmatically when app is running in background

Tags: objective-c, ios, background-image, homescreen, lockscreen

I am developing an iphone app where i have to change lockscreen image programmatically when app is running in background.I have got lots of stuff saying it is not possible but there is an app for this please let me know how to acheive this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can change the lockscreen image is when you are playing audio. Police Scanner+ does play audio, and therefore can set an image. This only works with iOS 5+ and is done something like this.

```
- (void)setupNowPlayingInfoCenter:(MPMediaItem *)currentSong
{
    NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    CGFloat version = 4.0;
    if ([ver length] >= 3)
    {
        version = [[ver substringToIndex:3] floatValue];
    }

    if (version >= 5.0)
    {
        MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [currentSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];

        if (currentSong == nil)
        {
            infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = nil;
            return;
        }

        infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle], MPMediaItemPropertyTitle,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist], MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle], MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount], MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber], MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber,
                artwork, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyComposer], MPMediaItemPropertyComposer,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount], MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber], MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyGenre], MPMediaItemPropertyGenre,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID], MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration], MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration,
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.mediaCollection.nowPlayingIndex + 1], MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueIndex,
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.mediaCollection count]], MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueCount, nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but can you help me in detail way how do i set image when audio is playing in background.Please help me with some source code.I am getting lots of error by this.

Comment: I was just creating a sample project when I came across [this guide](http://jaysonlane.net/2012/04/lock-screen-now-playing-with-mpnowplayinginfocenter/), which explains most of it anyway..

I don't think you can create your own MPMediaItemArtwork object, so I guess if you want a custom image, you can create a dummy mp3 file with the image, add it to your project, and create an MPMediaItem with that song. You can then access its MPMediaItemArtwork property as shown in the link.

Comment: @sam_899: with your code, I can put some info to the music control. Do you know how to update the music progress there? The progress doesnt change even i set the playback time.

Answer (score 0):

there is No way to do this effect unless a app runs in a jailbreak iDevice ( and it means the app can't be submitted to App Store).

Comment: but there is an app called Police Scanner+ on appstore which do the same it means it is acheivable

Comment: yes there is a hack way to handle it by playing no-sound tracks with custom album-image. but this trick is meaningless unless your app is a kind of music app.