# Best Way To Display Music Play Controls On Lock Screen iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, lockscreen, audio-player

I have a music app. What is the best way to have the song info and music controls show up in the lock screen like SoundCloud - see (http://cl.ly/image/1a1H041A1Z34)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty useful guide - [Lock screen “Now Playing” with MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](http://jaysonlane.net/2012/04/lock-screen-now-playing-with-mpnowplayinginfocenter/);

This only works with iOS 5+ and is done something like this.

```
- (void)setupNowPlayingInfoCenter:(MPMediaItem *)currentSong
{
    NSString *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    CGFloat version = 4.0;
    if ([ver length] >= 3)
    {
        version = [[ver substringToIndex:3] floatValue];
    }

    if (version >= 5.0)
    {
        MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [currentSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];

        if (currentSong == nil)
        {
            infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = nil;
            return;
        }

        infoCenter.nowPlayingInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle], MPMediaItemPropertyTitle,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist], MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle], MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount], MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber], MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber,
                artwork, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyComposer], MPMediaItemPropertyComposer,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount], MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber], MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyGenre], MPMediaItemPropertyGenre,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID], MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID,
                [currentSong valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration], MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration,
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.mediaCollection.nowPlayingIndex + 1], MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueIndex,
                [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self.mediaCollection count]], MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackQueueCount, nil];
    }
}
```

next time, try to use search:

- [Changing iphone lock screen programmatically when app is running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835380/changing-iphone-lock-screen-programmatically-when-app-is-running-in-background)

Comment: question is already flagged as duplicate, besides lifting code from question i added pretty useful tutorial with explanation to following code...